# add two li elements into the end of the ul

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is the **jsfiddle** that I tried to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/fxMFh/

I want to add two li's into the end of the submenu with jquery, but this seems that doesnt navigate to the ul it needs to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".navigation_container nav > ul > li > ul").append('<li><a href="#">test</a></li>');
});
```

this must be the problem:

```
$(".navigation_container nav > ul > li > ul")
```

I must be doing something very *noobish* here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".navigation_container nav > ul > li > div.sub-menu > ul").append('<li><a href="#">test</a></li>');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FczCs/)

But probably I will shorten the selector to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".navigation_container nav div.sub-menu > ul").append('<li><a href="#">test</a></li>');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FczCs/1/)

Comment: thank you this worked for me I am going to accept your answer after 7 mintes

Comment: another question, when I do this to my web site it doesnt work as in the jsfiddle it adds only the string test, not as link and li, what could be causing this?

Comment: Can you inspect the element using your browser's developer tools and see what is happening

Comment: yes after the last li its "test", its like removing the html from it

Comment: oh its ok I found the problem it is because I have added this code through some online editor and it removes html tags that is why it happened but any way thank you I am going to solve this by my self

Answer (score 1):

Three problems:

1. The fiddle doesn't include jQuery.
2. The selector is missing a div wrapper. It should be:

   `$(".navigation_container nav > ul > li > div > ul")`
3. `.appendTo()` should be `.append()`

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanbrill/fxMFh/5/

Comment: @ArunPJohny StackOverflow can be weird, sometimes. :)