# jQuery Deferred .then() isn't called after .fail()

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm using jQuery.Deferred and registering the `done`, `fail` and `then` handlers:

```
$.when( some_ajax(url) )
    .done(function(result){})
    .fail(function(){})
    .then(function(){}); //just like that, with a single parameter
```

I've found that when my ajax call succeeds, `done` and `then` callbacks are called, in this order. However when the ajax fails, the `fail` callback is called but I don't get to the `then` callback.

I've read the jQuery.Deferred documentation but couldn't find a hint regarding the reason for this behavior.

When using `always` instead of `then`, it is called in both cases - success and failure (first `done`/`fail` is called, then `always` is called). The documentation doesn't seem to indicate an expected difference between `always` and `then` in my described scenario, why do they behave differently?

Comment: Your call to `then()` only handles success, so it is quite normal for it not to handle the fail case (I think that's what Arun P Johny says in his answer). Or do you mean you're also passing a fail handler to `then()` in your actual code?

Comment: It is indeed clearer, and Arun's answer is right: your call to `then()` only handles success, not failure, so it is logical for the handler not to be called in case of failure.

Comment: now a close vote for too localized !!!!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The syntax of `.then()` is [.then(successCallback, failureCallbacl)](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) that is why in case of success both are called and in case of failure only `fail` is called.

In your case you are passing only one callback to the `.then()` method, it will be registered as a success callback, so you have two success callbacks one registered with `done()` and another one with `.then()`. But for error case you have only one callback registered with `.fail()`

If you want a callback to be called irrespective of success/failure then use [.always()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/)

Comment: I suspect your answer is right (we need more information from the questioner to be sure), but maybe it is not clear enough. I would suggest you try to clarify what you mean by *in case of success both are called*, right now it can be understood as *both the success and the failure handlers are called*, which is wrong. (In passing, I tried to offset the downvotes, but you probably should delete your immediately previous comment: it is redundant, can be seen as offensive, and does not help your case).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi yes probably, but I had enough of some crazy downvotes

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi sometimes even think of leaving the forum altogether

Comment: Sometime back I found another answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115180/add-two-li-elements-into-the-end-of-the-ul/16115214?noredirect=1#comment23028862_16115214 which was downvoted, I also provided same answer and it was accepted. But the another user was downvoted